# Using Ansible docker_service module to deploy service to swarm

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-swarm

I'm trying to deploy a Docker service into swarm but always ending up with running container on my localhost (the one I use as a docker swarm manager) and no service

Here's my setup:

I have 3 node Docker (v. 1.12.1) swarm that includes one host running as manager and two worker nodes all running on CentOS 7. On the manager node (localhost) I run Ansible (v. 2.1.1.0) playbook and the swarm is already configured and is running

```
Swarm: active
 NodeID: d9h5xa832ax7wzeq8q44fjld3
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 9cztoin3gy2ntbwehsmrkjuxi
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 3
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: 10.25.190.209
```

Starting with a playbook that has this code

```
- hosts: localhost
  name: Run JMeter test
  vars_files:
    - user.config.yml
  vars:
    execute_tpcds_test : "{{ run_tpcds_test }}"    
  roles:
    - { role: run_jmeter, when: execute_tpcds_test is defined and execute_tpcds_test ==1 }
```

Which calls this role:

```
- name: Deploy tpcds_tpg service to swarm
  docker_service:
    project_name: tpcds-tpg
    definition:
      version: '2'
      services:
        run_tests: 
          image: 'pbench/tpcds_tpg'
          volumes: 
            - /opt/pbench/run_output/
          command: ./run_jmeter.sh "{{jmeter_output_dir}}" 
  register: output
- debug: var=output
```

When I run `ansible-playbook ./site.yml` I end up with a running container. Doing `docker ps -a` displays

```
[pdo@sdl02133 tpcds-tpg]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
fef245b41365        pbench/tpcds_tpg   "./run_jmeter.sh /opt"   21 seconds ago      Up 20 seconds                           tpcdstpg_run_tests_1
```

And doing `docker service ls` shows no services running so it looks like `docker_service` deploys my image as a local container and not as a service on the swarm

So my assumption was that if I have an active swarm on the machine that is a swarm manager and I use Ansible `docker_service` module, then it will automatically be aware of the swarm and deploy the service to it. Looks like my assumption is wrong and I cannot find any docs, blog posts, etc. that would hint me what to do and what I am missing. Ansible experts please help!

Comment: Not sure why my question was downvoted. If there is anything else I am missing please tell me so and I will gladly add more details

Comment: It's not particularly related to software development.  This seems to be primarily about systems administration and networking, and there are better StackExchange sites for those sorts question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Ansible module uses Docker Compose](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_service_module.html#requirements-on-host-that-executes-module) which doesn't work with Swarm Mode at the moment. If you run `docker-compose` on a node in a Swarm, it just issues `docker run` commands - which is why you have containers running on a single host instead of services running in the Swarm.

You can track swarm mode support in Compose with [issue 3656](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3656), but when that does happen there may well need to be a change to the Ansible module too (unless Compose is changed to have swarm mode detection logic).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case, unfortunately. Thanks and enjoy the bounty!

Answer (score 2):

I created a [common task](https://gist.github.com/clems4ever/f033bc3806891d9ef2449e471cbfeb2a) to unblock myself until the swarm service module is implemented in Ansible. I'm aware it is not a 100% idempotent but it covers a majority of my use cases. It allows you to deploy any service from a registry or from a git repository with a Dockerfile. It also handles the docker networks.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't work with swarm mode introduced in docker 1.12, docker-compose then docker-service ansible module must be upgraded before. However it works if you use an 'old' swarm cluster built as described here : https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/ (Nota: I prefer to use a [consul discovery service](https://dzone.com/articles/docker-swarm-cluster-using-consul))

[docker-service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_service_module.html#notes) module expects some environment variables to be able to reach a swarm: DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY, DOCKER_CERT_PATH, ...

If you not set them, it use default configuration to use host local docker.

If you used docker-machine to create and reach your swarm cluster, you can type following command to retrieve them:

```
  docker-machine env --swarm <swarm_marster>
```

Otherwise, if you succeeded to reach your swarm cluster, you must have them anyway (is command `echo $DOCKER_HOST` returns something ?).

Then, in your playbook, you need to set needed enrivonment variables (you can use variables):

```
  - name: Deploy tpcds_tpg service to swarm
    docker_service:
      project_name: tpcds-tpg
      definition:
        version: '2'
        services:
          run_tests:
            image: 'pbench/tpcds_tpg'
            volumes:
              - /opt/pbench/run_output/
            command: ./run_jmeter.sh "{{jmeter_output_dir}}"
      docker_host: tcp://192.168.1.1:2376
      tls_verify: 1

    register: output
  - debug: var=output
```

> If you need to use DOCKER_CERT_PATH, related module parameter names are: tls_ca_cert, tls_client_cert and tls_client_key

Comment: According to this issue https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3656 compose is not integrated with swarm yet. Does docker-service provides more than just a wrapper on top of compose?

Comment: I'm not running docker-machine is there a way to get <swarm-master> without it? Or am I required to have docker-machine installed?

Comment: @Bostone: However, I succeeded to perform a docker-compose scale on a swarm cluster last month during a dojo. Docker-compose use docker to perform actions. If docker is configured to reach your swarm cluster, it's transparent for docker-compose.

Comment: @Bostone: How do you reach your swarm cluster ? What do you do to retrieve your cluster info ?

Comment: I use `docker info` which yields
 `Swarm: active
 NodeID: d9h5xa832ax7wzeq8q44fjld3
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 9cztoin3gy2ntbwehsmrkjuxi
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 3
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: 10.25.190.209`

Comment: Basically when setting a swarm you don't have to use docker-machine or so I understand. I have a cluster of one manager and 2 workers that I can deploy to from command line using `docker service`

Comment: OK, I didn't realize you're using swarm mode integrated with docker 1.12. I'm using old scholl approach: Create and reach a swarm cluster with docker machine. I'm gonna to update my examples and if I found a solution, I'll update my response.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to deploy containers copying Docker Compose file from host machine and running stack deploy on shell command:

```yaml
---
- hosts: leader
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Join Docker Network
      docker_network:
        name: traefik-public
        driver: overlay

    - name: Create Build Directory
      file:
        path: /home/ubuntu/container1
        state: directory
        owner: ubuntu
        group: ubuntu
        mode: '0755'

    - name: Copy Dockerfile
      copy:
        src: ./docker-compose.yml
        dest: /home/ubuntu/container1
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0644'

    - name: Docker Stack
      shell: docker stack deploy -c /home/ubuntu/container1/docker-compose.yml traefik
```